# Erroneous oscillation voltage for LC Tank in Cadence Virtuoso

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, oscillator, cadence, virtuoso

I simulated an LC tank with an ideal inductor and capacitor. The inductor's initial condition was 0 and the capacitor's was 300 mV.

I expected it to oscillate with an amplitude of 300 mV, but it oscillated with 3.7 V of amplitude. Here is the circuit and the corresponding waveform:

[image]

The waveform is shown below:

[image]

Is there any reason why I see this kind of behavior?

I am using Cadence Spectre as the simulator.

Comment: Does your software need to have one of the nodes explicitly as GND?

Comment: Oscillators are tricky in simulation.  The integration method used can influence the results as can other numerical options.

Comment: It works in micro-cap (600 mV p-p).

Comment: it won't 'oscillate' like that -- it will 'ring'.